# Kubernetes go client api for log of a particular pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am using kube go client with kube api to access kube data. I am currently not finding any api call for logs of a particular pod.

```
kubectl logs pod-name
```

returns the logs for a particular pod. How do I do this using go client? 
I am using v1.0.6 of kubernetes.

I can get the pod by using

```
client.Pods("namespace").Get("pod-name")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get logs from kubernetes using golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852530/how-to-get-logs-from-kubernetes-using-golang)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Client Go](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.20.2/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#PodExpansion) has offered a function `GetLogs` for this, which has been answered in [How to get logs from kubernetes using Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852530/how-to-get-logs-from-kubernetes-using-golang/53870271#53870271)

---

Looking at how kubectl implements its commands can be helpful when getting a feel for how to use the client library. In this case, [kubectl's implementation of the logs command](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c2e90cd1549dff87db7941544ce15f4c8ad0ba4c/pkg/kubectl/cmd/log.go#L188) looks like this:

```golang
    req := client.RESTClient.Get().
        Namespace(namespace).
        Name(podID).
        Resource("pods").
        SubResource("log").
        Param("follow", strconv.FormatBool(logOptions.Follow)).
        Param("container", logOptions.Container).
        Param("previous", strconv.FormatBool(logOptions.Previous)).
        Param("timestamps", strconv.FormatBool(logOptions.Timestamps))

    if logOptions.SinceSeconds != nil {
        req.Param("sinceSeconds", strconv.FormatInt(*logOptions.SinceSeconds, 10))
    }
    if logOptions.SinceTime != nil {
        req.Param("sinceTime", logOptions.SinceTime.Format(time.RFC3339))
    }
    if logOptions.LimitBytes != nil {
        req.Param("limitBytes", strconv.FormatInt(*logOptions.LimitBytes, 10))
    }
    if logOptions.TailLines != nil {
        req.Param("tailLines", strconv.FormatInt(*logOptions.TailLines, 10))
    }
    readCloser, err := req.Stream()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer readCloser.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(out, readCloser)
    return err
```

Comment: A more current answer that takes into account API chances can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53870271/2305837

Answer (score 0):

```
type Pipe struct {
    InReader  *io.PipeReader
    InWriter  *io.PipeWriter
    OutReader *io.PipeReader
    OutWriter *io.PipeWriter
}


req := client.RESTClient().Get().Resource("pods").
    Name(option.Name).Namespace(option.Namespace).SubResource("log")

opt := &coreV1.PodLogOptions{
    Follow:       option.Follow,
    Previous:     option.Previous,
    SinceSeconds: option.SinceSeconds,
    Timestamps:   option.Timestamps,
    TailLines:    option.TailLines,
    LimitBytes:   option.LimitBytes,
}
if option.Container != "" {
    opt.Container = option.Container
}

req.VersionedParams(
    opt,
    scheme.ParameterCodec,
)

exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(k.cli.kubeConfig, http.MethodGet, req.URL())
if err != nil {
    return err
}

err = exec.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
    Stdin:  pipe.InReader,
    Stdout: pipe.OutWriter,
    Stderr: pipe.OutWriter,
    Tty:    true,
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
return nil
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.