# Go/Kubernetes. How to get logs from pod?

Tags: go, kubernetes

Can you tell me how I can get the logs for the Pod I need?
I have code that outputs the status of one of the pods, and also outputs the number of pods in cluster. It works fine.
I took this code from https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go and edited it a bit.
But I don't understand, how can I get the logs of a pod for parsing them later?
I saw this question ([How to get logs from kubernetes using Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852530/how-to-get-logs-from-kubernetes-using-go/53870271#53870271)) But I can't figure out how I can change that code to make it work in my case.

```
func testKubernetesRequest() {
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    // use the current context in kubeconfig
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // create the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    pod, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").Get(context.TODO(), "shell-demo", metav1.GetOptions{})
    fmt.Println(pod.Status)
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("There are %d pods in the cluster\n", len(pods.Items)

}
```

Comment: this code will print to `stdout`. So unless the `stdout` is logged, it will not be available in log.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solve this issue, my problem was related to this packet  `corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"`, which you need to import except other which mention in `https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go`

```
 package main
    
    import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
)
func getPodLogs() {
    var kubeconfig *string
    podLogOpts := corev1.PodLogOptions{}

    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // create the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    req := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").GetLogs("name_of_pod", &podLogOpts)
    podLogs, err := req.Stream(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error in opening stream")
    }
    defer podLogs.Close()

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _, err = io.Copy(buf, podLogs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("")
    }
    str := buf.String()
    fmt.Println(str)    
}
```